# Issues with .css changes back to original settings

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css

I am nearing the end of my M2 dev site and ready to go live however I keep having one main issue. We have made some changes to some of the text on the home page, menu and my shop by brands page. We changed some of the text colors, sizes, alignment, and capitalized in the place of uppercase (and vice versa). These changes were made in .css files (styles-1.css, settings default.css) and also in Static > _cache > merged. The files located in the static > merge directories are long numbers example:
(045a82f864904fb393b1d9ac0992df53.css). These files keep changing almost daily. Not sure if the settings are changing each time these files change.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on and why my changes keep defaulting back to the original settings.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are generated and you should not edit them as is. You should check .less files and find those styles in that files. Then those files will be used to generate final css files.

You can read more about less compilation in Magento dev docs.